# Create a list with a number of objects from the local environment

Tags: r

ive created a lot of character objects in R that i would like to put into a list (storing all their information).
the object looks like this and the pattern is "TMC"

```
str(TMCS09g10086933)
 chr [1:10] "TMCS09g1008699" "TMCS09g1008610 "TMCS09g10086101" "TMCS09g10086104" "TMCS09g100864343" "TMCS09g10086434343" "TMCS09g10086994111" ...
```

i have hundreds of these objects. Could someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to find the objects, which you can do with a regex search through the list of the objects in your environment `grep("^TMC", ls(), value = TRUE)`, then you need to get the objects using the character vector of their names. For that you use `mget`.

```
your_list <- mget(grep("^TMC", ls(), value = TRUE))
```

Comment: i know i could be another question, but could you please point me to a way to intersect all the objects with their contents? my aim is obtaining a binary matrix. i already tried with the function `fromList` of `upsetR` but apparently the rownames are displayied as numbers from 1 to the number of shared objects. What i want is to actually keep (and thus visualize) their names in the resulting dataframe

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `objects` with the argument `pattern` to list them.

Then, you can call the function `get` to fetch them. If you do this with an `lapply`, you will get a `list` returned right away.

```
TMClist <- lapply(objects(pattern = "^TMC"), get)
```

Comment: upvoted because it works. you do, though, loop instead of just using the vector structure of the object

Comment: indeed, `mget` is a bit nicer than `get`